# fast code instead of for loop with if

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if you see a fast way in MATLAB to convert the following "for" loop into a one-line calculation that is more efficient.

```
A=[2;4;0;6;1;0];
B=[1;3;0;4;0;5];
C=[2,4,8,5,7;
11,44,2,8,9;
43,2,1,87,3;
13,26,7,9,3;
12,2,6,3,23;
18,42,6,7,2];
for i=1:size(A,1)
 D(i,1)=i-1;
if (A(i,1)~=0)
    if (B(i,1)==0)
        D(i,2)=0;
    else
            D(i,2)=C(A(i,1),B(i,1));
    end
else
                D(i,2)=0;
end
end
```

Comment: Initialising `D` beforehand, e.g. `D=[0:(size(A,1)-1), zeros(1,size(A,1))].'` already improves quite a bit, since you are no longer dynamically growing a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use `sub2ind` :

```
D=zeros(numel(A),2);

D(:,1)=0:(numel(A)-1);

LinearIds=sub2ind(size(C),A(A~=0&B~=0),B(A~=0&B~=0));

D(A~=0&B~=0,2)=C(LinearIds);
```

### Output :

```
D =

    0   11
    1    7
    2    0
    3    7
    4    0
    5    0
```